# scanner delimiter to get tokens separated by " " and "\n" java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, token, delimiter

I am trying to read tokens from a file that looks like this

```
4 2
3 1 2 3
```

So I want these tokens to be delimited by " " or by enter (\n).
How do I achieve this?

I tried something, but with no success.

```
in = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
        scan = new Scanner(in);

        scan.useDelimiter(" \\n");

        System.out.println("I get here");

        t = new Translator(Integer.parseInt(scan.next()), Integer.parseInt(scan.next()));

        System.out.println("I don't get here");

        int temp = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
        while(temp > 0){
            m.final_states.add(Integer.parseInt(scan.next()));
            temp--;
        }
```

I can't seem to find any relevant information about the kind of delimiters that I want. I've seen a couple of examples, I've read the example in the documentation too, but I am confused.

The error I get is java.lang.NumberFormatException

Comment: What is the default delimiter of a Scanner, according to the javadoc? How does the javadoc define the default delimiter?

Comment: Your pattern matches a space followed by a newline, not a space or a newline.

Comment: @JBNizet it is indeed the whitespace.. oops. I thought it wouldn't work on enter, but I see it does

Comment: @nfnneil your answer was helpful, but I can't mark it as correct answer because it's not the answer to what i wrote in the title

Comment: @Bubletan good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good thing about `Scanner` is that it allows to read primitive types w/o explicit casting. You may try the following approach:

```
try (FileInputStream source = new FileInputStream(PATH)) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source);
    Translator translator = new Translator(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
    while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
        m.final_states.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }    
}
```

Please note that with the help of the `scanner.hasNextInt()` you don't need to count # of your inputs in the second line.

Answer (score 1):

A very common issue is you forget to trim the string.  Try this:

```
m.final_states.add(Integer.parseInt(scan.next().trim()));
```

and

```
t = new Translator(Integer.parseInt(scan.next().trim()), Integer.parseInt(scan.next().trim()));
```

Comment: it may be also that, but it still doesn't work :( thank you for your answer

Comment: it worked! it's fine :D i didn't have to use custom delimiters at all. also, it doesn't work without trim, so thank you, again